# Passing JAR files as CMD arguments that are required as dependencies

Tags: java, jar, command-line-arguments

I have a program running in Intellij Idea. It has the following dependencies added as a jar file

[image]

I want to run it using the command line and want it to detect the jar files automatically as dependencies. Is there any way to achieve that without using Gradle or Maven? Or I could pass the dependencies as command-line arguments?

I have tried this command but it throws an error:

```
 javac -classpath lib/*.jar -sourcepath src/*
```

Error:

```
error: invalid flag: lib/okhttp-3.4.1.jar
```

Using java -cp says this:

```
 java -cp lib/* -sourcepath src/*
```

error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class lib.okhttp-3.4.1.jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: lib.okhttp-3.4.1.jar
```

Used the suggested command and it says:

```
 java -cp lib/gson-2.10.jar:lib/okhttp-3.4.1.jar:lib/okio-3.2.0.jar:lib/slf4j-api-2.0.6.jar  src/Main.java
```

[image]

Comment: Just include all jars in the classpath at the command line - not a problem

Comment: @g00se how do I do that?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @g00se Ubuntu 22.10

Comment: `java -cp x.jar:y.jar:z.jar foo.bar.X`

Comment: @g00se I just updated the question. could you please review it

Comment: what do you mean by foo.bar.x?

Comment: You can't really recurse-compile like you're doing there. If you want to use the command line (I do) then really you need to be using a build tool like Maven

Comment: @g00se could you share a source mentioning that. As earlier I did it using gradle and can run it but the employ want it running without gradle and if I need him to understand the thing to use maven or gradle, I need to give him a doc mentioning this.

Comment: i am not good at compiling java using commands as I have always been doing it using IDE or using Gradle or mvn

Comment: Running is different from compiling. You just showed a *compiling* command line. Your employer is absolutely right about it needing to *run* without build tool assistance. Compiling without build tools is not really practicable unless the codebase is very small

Comment: I have just a few classes there. I just want to run the code using those libraries included as dependencies. I am not finding a way to do it using command line.

Comment: I posted an example command to do that. You just need to get the jar paths right and use the correct name for your main class

Comment: @g00se i used this command ` java -cp lib/gson-2.10.jar:lib/okhttp-3.4.1.jar:lib/okio-3.2.0.jar:lib/slf4j-api-2.0.6.jar  src/Main.java
` but the compilation error is there.

Comment: *... but the compilation error is there* But that has nothing to do with compilation. As I mentioned, compilation is hard without a build tool

Comment: `find src -type f -name \*.jar -exec javac -d mybin -classpath mybin:lib/*.jar '{}' \;` might do it for you, putting classes into ./mybin but I don't recommend it

Comment: @g00se so you recommend using an IDE for this

Comment: Not an ide necessarily but a build tool to compile . Your boss is talking about *running* the application.

Comment: yeah. he is talking about running the application. I have compiled a JAR file with Libraries and it is working now. Hope it goes that way or otherwise I will look for some other solution